# Laravel Billing Package

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a laravel billing & subscription application using laravel billing package. I have the api of Rave payment for the payment part. I want to know if the laravel billing package allows integration of another payment platform please? If not, is there any other package that can support that please?

PS: This might not qualify to be a S.O question but might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Laravel default package support is for Stripe and Braintree
But you can utilize  any 3rd party apis integration

Comment: this might help you for rave https://github.com/Flutterwave/Flutterwave-Rave-PHP-SDK

Comment: okay so you mean, aside the stripe and Braintree, i can integrate my own payment api into laravel default package support ?

Comment: default package have more support than other else you can use any other api

Comment: yes, i have checked that on laravel documentation but it doesn't show how you can integrate any other payment api